# Errors during export of osgi plugin for Domino

Tags: eclipse, osgi, lotus-domino

I have developed an osgi plugin for Domino. It contains a servlet which needs to check ACL settings.

I have a target platform based on ...Domino/rcp/plugins and ...Domino/shared/plugins. The jre is the installed Domino jre.

The servlet imports lotus.domino and uses lotus.domino.ACL. The plugin manifest contains a dependancy on lotus.domino.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: MyServletPlugin
Bundle-SymbolicName: MyServletPlugin;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.1.20121026
Bundle-Activator: de.xyz.Activator
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Import-Package: lotus.domino,
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry,
 org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet,
 org.eclipse.osgi,
 org.eclipse.osgi.services,
 org.eclipse.osgi.util,
 com.ibm.pvc.servlet;bundle-version="2.5.0"
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/gson-1.6.jar,
 .
```

When I export the plugin using the Export Wizard I get an error.

```
Errors occured during the export operation.
```

The log file contains the following:

```
# 26.10.12 12:33:32 MESZ
# Eclipse Compiler for Java(TM) 0.B83_R37x, 3.7.2, Copyright IBM Corp 2000, 2011. All  rights reserved.
----------
1. ERROR in D:\workspace\osgiservlet\WireitServletPlugin\src\de\xyz\AclServlet.java (at line 14)
    import lotus.domino.ACL;
           ^^^^^
The import lotus cannot be resolved
----------
2. ERROR in D:\workspace\osgiservlet\WireitServletPlugin\src\de\xyz\AclServlet.java (at line 15)
    import lotus.domino.ACLEntry;
           ^^^^^
The import lotus cannot be resolved
```

... and many more like this.

The Domino version is 8.5.3 and eclipse is Indigo SR2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I have found the cause.

When I set up the project I added a sepate project which just contained the Notes.jar. I assume this was recommended on blog or something.

It had worked ok so I'm not sure what went wrong. In any case, I removed the project and the export is now successful.

Comment: @shydownvoter - why? what do you disagree with? Be constructive!

Answer (score 2):

Add "com.ibm.notes.java.api" as a required plug-in and remove lotus.domino from the imported packages. That should solve the problem.